# jQuery attr(); with iframe?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to use the jQuery `.attr()` property to get the height of an iframe *or* an img with an explicitly defined height.

**jQuery**

```
var scrollerHeight = $('.caroufredsel_wrapper > ul > li').find('img','iframe').attr('height');
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="caroufredsel_wrapper">
<ul>
    <li><iframe src="movie.swf" width="750" height="422"></iframe></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

As it is written now, I'm getting 'undefined' as a value. Any ideas on how to solve this?

JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/LmMTL/1/

Comment: What values is it giving you?

Comment: Try checking with firebug, see what the current attributes are, it's possible you changed them elsewhere

Comment: Seems to work fine with the img tag, but the iframe is giving me 'undefined'

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you should supply only one argument to `.find()` -> selector `'img, iframe'`

```
var scrollerHeight = $('.caroufredsel_wrapper > ul > li').find('img, iframe').attr('height');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LmMTL/2/

Comment: @ElliotBonneville No. The quotes between `img` and `iframe` are removed.

Comment: Oops, you're right. Very small change, hard to see when scrolling up and down. :) @tarmaq: I'm canceling my downvote, but you should specify what you changed next time to prevent confusion. :p

Answer (score 5):

This is wrong:

```
.find('img','iframe')
```

`find()` doesn't accept any extra parameters. I think you mean this:

```
.find('img, iframe')
```

Comment: The two snippets are exactly the same

Comment: @Starx: Nope, the quotes are changed. :p

Comment: @Starx No it's not - there is only one string argument passed to `$.find()` instead of two in the OP.

Comment: @ElliotBonneville, No I meant his answer, I was on his first edit

Answer (score 0):

You could always just give the iframe an id attr. I tested that on your jsFiddle and got 422 as the result.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you set an id to the frame an access it directly.

```
var scrollerHeight = $('#mframe').attr('height');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LmMTL/7/

Comment: That would work, but I'm working with a CMS and the iframe will change.

Comment: well you should use find('img, iframe') since find only accepts one parameter .find( selector );

Answer (score 0):

The find() method uses Selector context, so it is treating the second parameter as an alternate context. The alternate context  is normally used to direct the selector to a different DOM.

Changing your find selector to use multiple elements in the first parameter will work.

Height = $('.caroufredsel_wrapper > ul > li').find('img, iframe').attr('height');

I also recommend using the first filter/method to ensure you only get back one result:

$('.caroufredsel_wrapper > ul > li').find('iframe, img').first().attr('height');

See my test gist here: https://gist.github.com/2321394

Answer (score 0):

this one is wrong

```
    .find('img','iframe')
```

try this one

```
   $(document).ready(function() {


  var scrollerHeight = $('.caroufredsel_wrapper > ul > li').find('iframe').attr('height');
  alert(scrollerHeight);

 });
```